# How to display an ErrorDialog, if a service failed

Tags: android, service

I have a DownloadService which I use to fetch websites, in order to update some app-data.

This is how I call the service in an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class );
intent.putExtra(this.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_URL, url);
intent.putExtra(DownloadService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_RECEIVER, new DownloadReceiver());
this.startService(intent);
```

However, it's possible that the download fails, in which case the Service notifies the DownloadReceiver.

*(The `DownloadReceiver` extends `ResultReceiver`, and gets a Bundle that includes state, the downloaded html and - in case of an error - an errormessage)*

How can I display an ErrorDialog if this happenes? The resultReceiver doesn't have access to the Context.

Comment: make a status callback for this. (interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a handler in your main activity. pass this handler to your Downloadreceiver wherein if any error occurs you send a message to main activity from where you can display an alert using AlertDialog/Fragment i.e. in handleMessage() you check the message and show the alert.

Comment: What would happen, if I switch the Activity before the Download finished? I guess that I have a huge Memory Leak, because the GC can't collect the old activity, and an exception as soon as I try to use the old Context?

Comment: as you are downloading in a service,you cant stop the download.

Comment: you are passing the handler to the receiver which you should register in `onResume()` of your activity and unregister the same in `onStop()`

Comment: @upenpat : Your approach will fail if the `Activity` no longer exists. Much better to use a `Notification`.

Comment: I mean that in the activity in which he updates the data based on the response he should register/unregister.

Comment: sorry for saying main activity in my answer actually it should be the activity which is going to be updated. thanks Squonk.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display dialog from Service or Receiver. But you can display either error message in notification bar, or can display an toast containing error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (url == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Sorry! unable to download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can use something of the sort to display a toast message